# How to free up disk space on a drive which has BiztalkMsgBoxDB_log file in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, biztalk, database-administration

I have been asked to analyze a issue regarding one of the biztalk servers. I was asked to free up space on a particular drive, where I found the only file BiztalkMsgBoxDB_log.bak is taking up close 90% of the drive.
Running the following query I later found out that the log space used is only 1.25%.

***EXEC ('DBCC sqlperf(LOGSPACE) WITH NO_INFOMSGS')***

```
**Database Name**   **Log Size (MB)**   **Log Space Used (%)**  **Status**
  BizTalkMsgBoxDb     24930.49            1.257622                0
```

currently the Recovery Mode is : FULL and the transaction log back up was taken an hour ago.

I have no clue as to why the log file was created so large.
How can I free up data on this drive.

Thanks in advance,
GHR

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Try [sf]

Comment: *.bak is a backup file. Assuming you are referring to the *.ldf (log file) it will hold the size that is available even when the transaction logs are taken. The way to reduce the size is to shrink the log file using the option to release unused space to OS

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your suggestion, will there be any issues shrinking the log file knowing that 98.75% is unused? what should be the size of the log file after shrink. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to shrink your database 
Right click on your database => Shrink that's it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "Backup BizTalk Server Job" is properly configured and is not failing (check the SQL Server Agent node on the BizTalk database server).

For reference on how to configure this job (and more details of what it does), check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa546765.aspx).

Comment: After the shrink I see the backup jobs are working fine.